# Matlab crashes while running a mex function with some data

Tags: c, matlab, crash, mex

I have written a mex function(in C) which takes 2 arrays and a scalar as input and after doing some mathematical calculation it returns a scalar quantity as output. I can compile the corresponding mex function successfully on the MATLAB platform but as soon as I am gonna run it with some input data, its causing a crash to MATLAB. The error log has a heading "Segmentation Violation detected at Mon Apr 25 ..:..:.. 2016". I also tried to debug it in Linux platform using the GNU debugger 'gdb'. It is showing a problem with all the if statements that I have used to verify the number and type of input/output arguments using nrhs,prhs[],nlhs,plhs[]. For example my first statement for checking the number of input arguments is,

```
if(nrhs!=3) 
   mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Three inputs required.");
```

and likewise others for nlhs. The GNU debugger is placing its first breakpoint at the above if statement and if I am commenting it out it is causing a problem with the second if statement following this and likewise. When I am commenting out all the if statements the mex function is running successfully and also giving me the desired output.

It's been long since I am trying to remove this bug by reading all the available answers but I am not unable to do so. Please help me with the above problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is the actual code:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    double *Ip, *Is;            /* Input data vectors */
    double r;               /* Value of r (input) */
    double *dist;           /* Output ImED distance */
    size_t ncols;           /* For storing the size of input vector */

    /* Checking for proper number of arguments */
    if(nrhs!=3) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Three inputs required.");

    if(nlhs!=1) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Only one output required.");

    /* make sure the first input argument(value of r) is scalar */
    if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0])!=1 ) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Value of r must be a scalar.");

    /* make sure that the input vectors are of type double */
    if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[2]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[2]))          
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Input vectors must be of type double.");       

    /* Make sure that the output is of type double and is a scalar */
    if(!mxIsDouble(plhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(plhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(plhs[0])!=1) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Image Euclidean Distance must be a scalar.");

    /* check that number of rows in input arguments is 1 */
    if(mxGetM(prhs[1])!=1 || mxGetM(prhs[2])!=1) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Inputs must be row vectors."); 

    /* Get the value of r */
    r = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

    /* Getting the input vectors */
    Ip = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    Is = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

    ncols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

    /* Creating link for the scalar output */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    dist = mxGetPr(plhs[0]); 

    imedDistCal(r,Ip,Is,(mwSize)ncols,dist);
}
```

Comment: From the error log it seems that you attemp to access protected, read-only, or unallocated memory. I'd start by checking loops and indices.

Comment: Please show the actual code too.

Comment: @rayryeng Please see the actual code.

Comment: @ritualmagick: I have checked all the loops and possible memory access problems but everything seems fine to me.

Comment: I'd check for scalars using ``mxIsScalar()`` instead of ``mxGetNumberOfElements()``. Also, you can't run these checks on ``plhs[0]`` before it's initialized (this is why MATLAB crashes). If you move the if-checks on ``plhs[0]`` to after you "create the link", it should work fine. Another suggestion is to use ``plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(dist);`` (remember to use ``double dist`` instead of ``double *dist`` if you go for this solution).

Comment: @ritualmagick: Thanks for pointing out that. That was really something which completely missed my eyes. I wanted a check on the output scalar also and wrongly put it up there.    But, I would like to point that  plhs[0]= mxCreateDoubleScalar(dist) will not work in my case because I am going to store some value in my dist variable by calling that last function but dist will not be able to contain that unless a pointer to dist is passed to that function. Only then it can store the calculated value in its address.

Comment: Glad I could help out. About the pointer vs scalar; you're absolutely right. I ignored the part of the code where you call your other function, so I didn't check how ``dist`` was used there. 

If moving the if-checks solves your problem I can post it as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: Yeah...you can post that to be as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, MATLAB crashes because the `mxWhateverFunction(plhs[0]) <-- fill in for whatever` results in an invalid address when `plhs[0]` isn't linked to any variable prior to the tests.

The following piece of code

```
 if(!mxIsDouble(plhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(plhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(plhs[0])!=1) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error..Image Euclidean Distance must be a scalar.");
```

should be moved to after the following to avoid this problem.

```
   /* Creating link for the scalar output */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    dist = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
```

Comment: Though the code is running fine now but it is crashing for input arrays of size 1 X 1638400 which is well within the limits. I have also tried compiling it using the flag -largeArrayDims but it went in vain. Can you please throw some light on this issue.

Comment: Can you post the code of ``imedDistCal(r,Ip,Is,(mwSize)ncols,dist);`` so I can try to compile the complete code (e.g. upload to pastebin or something similar)? Hard to tell w/o having that.

Comment: Can't see anything that should result in a crash due to number of elements, but the nested will definitely take "forever" when you use a dimension of 1x1638400. What's the algorithm in the ``imedDistCal()`` function? Maybe there's a better way to implement that one?

Comment: It's really difficult to discuss that algorithm in this thread. Let me check for any other alternatives or can I write another mex function for doing the inner loop part and then calling it from this mex function. Will this be of any help for me?

Comment: Just thought if you maybe could link to a source where I can see the math behind it. Otherwise, it seems to me that you can cut out some of the loops w/o affecting the end result; move ``temp[i]`` to inner loop, and ``ans`` to outer loop; in this way you get rid of two loops.

However, it will still take a long time to run with those dimensions (unless you can do some parallel processing or even port to GPU-code).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative but that also doesn't work. Anyways I think I should write a GPU version of this and try running it in the workstation. Thanks for helping all the way.